# threaded and asyncio API library

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In Python I am trying to create an API for a connected device. I want to be available for both threaded (using request) and async applications (using aiohttp).
What I've come up with is wrapping the get method of both `requests` and `aiohttp` in a decorator. This decorator is passed at init and API calls are explicitly wrapped using the passed decorator.

It works, but I'd like to know how others think of this approach ? Are there better ways or will I be running into issues later on ?

Any help appreciated !

```
def threaded_gett(function):
    # The threaded decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        url, params = function(*args)
        response = requests.get(url, params)
        _json = response.json()
        return function.__self__.process_response(_json)

    return wrapper

def async_gett(function):
    # The async decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        url, params = function(*args)
        try:
            resp = yield from function.__self__.session.get(url, params=params)
        except Exception as ex:
            lgr.exception(ex)
        else:
            _json = yield from resp.json()
            yield from resp.release()
            return function.__self__.process_response(_json)

    # wrapping the decorator in the async coroutine decorator.
    wrapper = asyncio.coroutine(wrapper)
    return wrapper


class ThreadedApi(BaseApi):
    def __init__(self,threaded_gett):
        Base.__init(self,threaded_gett)


class AsyncApi(BaseApi):
    def __init__(self,async_gett):
        Base.__init(self,async_gett)


class BaseApi():
    def __init__(self,get_wrapper):
        self.status = get_wrapper(self.status)

    def status(self):
        return <status path>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question asking for a code review should be asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KlausD. This question has been [cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/147586/9357), but it is currently on hold there because the code is too hand-wavy to be considered working code.

Comment: @200_success Thanks for the info, but it doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: @KlausD. Agreed. It should also be closed on Stack Overflow because there is no specific programming problem identified in the question.

Comment: Ok. New here. Should I close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not complete but yes, the approach might work in simple cases (when `.process_response()` is very generic and could be applied to all API calls).